# Trying to get value from an input file sheet throws Runtime Error '13': typemismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to access the files that I select with 2 `GetOpenFilename`, the thing is
I have my two GetOpenFilename inside

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "Please select Inventory File"
inventory = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text files(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Please select Inventory File")
Set inventoryWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(inventory)
MsgBox "Please select Material List File"
MaterialList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text files(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Please select Material List File")
Set materialListWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(MaterialList)
Call Process(inventoryWorkbook, materialListWorkbook)
End Sub
```

and I'm trying to call the Sub Process that will handle both input files, this "Process" is in a module, at first I had this:

```
Call Process
```

and modified to Public Sub Process()

But that threw Runtime Error '424': Object Required

So I changed it to

```
 Call Process(inventoryWorkbook, materialListWorkbook)
```

and Module:

```
Public Sub Process(inventoryWorkbook, materialListWorkbook)
MsgBox "Enters"
Set MaterialList_Main = materialListWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set MainProjectCode = MaterialList_Main.Range("B2").Value
MsgBox MainProjectCode
End Sub
```

but It throws Runtime Error '13': Type Mismatch, I have no idea where is the TypeMismatch or how to fix it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Option Explicit at the top of each module (also the Thisworkbook Module).
This will dramatically reduce the number of type mismatches.

```
Option Explicit 

Dim MaterialList As String
Dim materialListWorkbook as Excel.Workbook

MaterialList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text files(*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Please select Material List File")
Set materialListWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(MaterialList)

Call Process(inventoryWorkbook)
```

And there is an error here:

```
Public Sub Process(inventoryWorkbook As Excel.Workbook, materialListWorkbook As Excel.Workbook)
    dim MaterialList_Main as Excel.Worksheet
    dim MainProjectCode as String 

    MsgBox "Enters" 
    Set MaterialList_Main = materialListWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 
    MainProjectCode = MaterialList_Main.Range("B2").Value 'Error: no Set for value! 
    MsgBox MainProjectCode 
End Sub
```

The Set keyword is only used for objects, not regular variables.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I'll be alert not to make this same mistake again.